# Forge BIM360 data management

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to repeat and comprehend the following solution for copying files from BIM360 by Augusto Goncalves:
https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/data.management-csharp-a360sync.git

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGCfX.png)

After filling FORGE_ID and FORGE_SECRET as [shown](https://youtu.be/4Pgg05tLW-M) it says that "Page exired". What I'm doind wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest making your callback url - http://localhost:58966/api/forge/callback/oauth it needs to return you the code for authentication.